# A better php array_merge

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I am looking to do this a better way without the need to hardcode the integers for `$justPrices[$i]`:

```
$pricesResult = array_merge($justPrices[0], $justPrices[1], $justPrices[2], $justPrices[3]);
```

`$justPrices` is a multidimensional array, containing 4 'bands' of prices within each array. The data for `$justPrices` being for example:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 40.95 [1] => 39.95 [2] => 39.45 [3] => 38.95 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 45.80 [1] => 41.80 [2] => 41.50 [3] => 41.40 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 45.95 [1] => 42.95 [2] => 41.95 [3] => 41.45 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 50.00 [1] => 50.00 [2] => 50.00 [3] => 50.00 ) )
```

The issue is that the amount of arrays within `$justPrices` will vary from at least 2 to 10+. So I need a way for the parameters for the `array_merge()` function to vary dependent on the amount of arrays within `$justPrices`. I was going to use this simple method to get the amount of arrays within `$justPrices`:

```
$justPricesMax = count($justPrices);
```

I could write a `for loop`, and I might still, I just wondered if there was a better method for what seems on the surface relatively simple!

Comment: @Gumbo a single array containing all the prices. I am using that for an average price thing afterwards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want to flatten the array, you can use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) to call `array_merge` with the elements of `$justPrices` as parameters:

```
$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $justPrices);
```

This is equivalent to a the function call:

```
$flat = array_merge($justPrices[0], $justPrices[1], … , $justPrices[count($justPrices)-1]);
```