# How can I merge multiple separate arrays that are not included in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

How is it possible to merge multiple separate arrays stored in a variable that are not included in an array themselves ?  The variable `$unique_answer_title` contains these separate arrays, however , I am trying to combine all their elements into one big numerical array.. when I use `array_merge($unique_answer_title)`, nothing gets returned. Below is the data contained in the variable ..

```
array(4) {
        [0]=> string(9) "Immediate" 
        [1]=> string(3) "Yes" 
        [2]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" 
        [3]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" 
        } 

    array(8) { 
        [0]=> string(9) "Immediate" 
        [1]=> string(3) "Yes" 
        [2]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" 
        [3]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" 
        [4]=> string(9) "Immediate" 
        [5]=> string(2) "No" 
        [6]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" 
        [7]=> string(111) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> NX<sup>P</sup> Workstation " 
        } 

    array(12) { 
        [0]=> string(9) "Immediate" 
        [1]=> string(3) "Yes" 
        [2]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" 
        [3]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" 
        [4]=> string(9) "Immediate" 
        [5]=> string(2) "No" 
        [6]=> string(29) "Have a representative call me" 
        [7]=> string(111) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> NX<sup>P</sup> Workstation " 
        [8]=> string(20) "Greater than 3 years" 
        [9]=> string(3) "Yes" 
        [10]=> string(42) "Have a representative contact me via email" 
        [11]=> string(109) "Biomek<sup><em>&#135;&#135;</em></sup> FX<sup>P</sup> Workstation" 
        }
```

Comment: `array_merge` is used to merge different arrays, but it seems that your var `$unique_answer_title` is an array containing all sub array. So you should instead do something like `array_merge($unique_answer_title[0], $unique_answer_title[1], ...)` to merge the content. Note that you can give all sub array to the function. If you don't know in advance the number of sub-array, then you will have to iterate to merge sequentially

Comment: I am afraid $unique_answer_title is not an array, but a *string* In this case you are going to have first to separate the arrays, then to eval each code. Not really a good way to do it either, eval is a bunch of security holes if you don't control fully the code to evaluate

Comment: If `$unique_answer_title` is a string, instead, it will be more complicated, you will have to parse the string in order to re create your arrays, but its really weird. What is the purpose ?

Comment: no , it's not a string .. when I var_dump it , it returns what I copied above .. without any type of its own .. only shows the multiple arrays in it

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question in code is:

```
$merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $unique_answer_title);
```

This is turning the one array you have into multiple parameters to [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) which accepts any number of parameters.

It had been previously (Sep 2010) outlined in:

- [A better php array_merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634670/a-better-php-array-merge)

If you then complain about double values, this has been handled already as well:

- [PHP merge array(s) and delete double values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6180090/367456)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop through each of them and the merge them:

```
$test = array(
 array(
  "Immediate",
  "Yes"
 ),
 array(
  'Test 2',
  'test 3'
 ),
 array(
  'test4',
  'test5'
 )
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($test as $array) $new_array = array_merge($new_array, $array);

var_dump($new_array);
```

Really, what you're asking is how to flatten a multi-dimensional array, the following may also be helpful: [How to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array into a simple one in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Comment: Justin , those are separate ARRAYS .. they're not into an array otherwise it would have been easy to do .. that's the problem ...

Comment: You need to add some code (or a var export or something) with your question, because your question states they are in one variable.

Comment: Yes , they are in one variable , but they're all separate arrays .. the data you see in the question is what var_dump($unique_answer_title) returns ... I think I really made it clear.

Comment: I think I answered what you requested. However, maybe what you are wanting that final array to be ONLY the unique values? If so, on the final array just do [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).